# Webservice based socket client

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, sockets

I am developing a socket based communicate between an webservice(socket client) and an external server. Since webservices are multithreaded (server created one thread for each service request), should each thread open a new socket (on given port) with the external server or the socket client should be synchronized and shared between webservice threads.
I am getting confused here. Is open client Socket (Object of java.net.Socket) is an expensive object like JDBC Connection or it can be (should be) open by each thread and closed by thread when it is done.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about creating a new `Socket` in the client for each request to the server, then that is the correct way to do it.

That's is exactly how browsers with tabs also work.

Having a single synchronized `Socket` means you need to have a map/table of thread name/id, request URL/or any other unique id or any other id to identify from which thread the request originated and to which thread the response must be forwarded to. This will definitely case performance issues and not scalable.

Comment: In the scenario where all threads share same socket, can I use blockQueues. Since the threads can produce request and consume response, can i have singleton component say "Soketer" who holds the socket and have two BlockQueues (incoming & outgoing). Any message on outgoing queue is written on socket and any message from socket is sent to incoming queue. All the threads have a reference to Sockert object.